# magento 2, cookie notice does not appear in home page

Tags: magento2, cookie, home-page

Cookie Restriction mode is enabled in admin panel. I see `<div class="message global cookie" id="notice-cookie-block">` is exist in other page but missing in home page. What could cause this? Any thing related to cache?